# 12VAC to 12VDC Converter Requirements for RGB LED Controller

Tags: transformer, converter, led-strip, ac-dc, bridge-rectifier

I have an outdoor lighting transformer (operating at the usual `12VAC`) that I want to add a strip of LED lights in a new run. The transformer has two legs, each supplying up to `300W` of load at either `12V`, `13V`, `14V`, or `15V` (4 contacts per leg). The strip light controller takes `12VDC` at up to `12A`, but I will only be connecting a single strip that consumes `5A` (`+1A` margin).

I know that to convert the power source to DC I will need a bridge rectifier and then something to smooth the ripple. I'm not sure what the tolerance of the RGB controller is (guessing `0.5V`, I might be able to confirm that tonight). Based on my research over the past few days it sounds like the **BR** will boost the output DC voltage (due to RMS vs peak) so I will need some resistors or diodes to drop the voltage back down to `12VDC`. As this converter will be living outside my intent is to keep things compact enough that I can weather proof it without much effort (either small enclosure, or epoxy and heat-shrink tubing).

I have a reasonable understanding of how the circuit design should look, but where I am not confident is on the specs of the components. For the **BR**, is at least `6A If` reasonable or should I pad that with at least `12A If` (especially if I want to add another `6A` run on the end of this run)? A `20A If` **BR** is only about `$2.00` so no big deal on price. All **BR**'s in this range seem to support very large peak reverse voltages (usually `600V+`), are there any minimum specs I should take note of?

For capacitance, I am using the `C = I / (Vdrop * Ifreq * 2)` formula. In my case that is `C = 6 / (0.5 * 60 * 2) = 100 mF` which seems very high, but perhaps necessary for this type of circuit (with load this high)? Is it more reasonable to use multiple caps instead? I know that I will need `25V` caps to handle the 12VDC coming out of the **BR**. I can pick up a cap with these specs for about `$6.00` so again, no big deal price wise.

Are there any other considerations that I should be aware of? I am certainly not a professional electrician, but I understand the general concepts. Building the circuit and soldering the parts together is no problem for me, it's just some of the finer details that I would like some feedback on to make sure I'm on the right track.

Finally, what I am attempting to recreate is a product available on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00SGMW4K8) but not available in Canada (where I live). Based on it's size and shape I'm almost certain that it is composed of a **BR** and (at least one) capacitor. Possibly some other parts to regulate the voltage?

Here is a (very basic) circuit diagram that I am expecting to build. I just put `1kOhm` for the controller as a reasonable amount of *load resistance* for the LED strip (not sure what the actual value is, but maybe I can figure that out later).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUZU9x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Isn't Canada 60Hz mains?

Comment: it sure is. oops, i'll correct the typo.

Comment: What DC current do you need at 12V DC?

Comment: at least `6A` (`300 LEDs * 0.24W / 12VDC`)

Comment: 12VAC is the RMS value correct? If so, then your DC output would be around 16 V.

Comment: Yes, I assume the transformer is outputting 12VAC RMS. The diagram above is a basic sketch, I would require something to step the output down to 12VDC.

Comment: One suggestion is to use the highest voltage tap (15V). Rectify it. Allow a much greater voltage drop with the filter cap to get the size down. Use a step down (buck) voltage regulator to get the 12V (assuming that is what the RGB controller needs). Probably just buy the regulator module. Some sources of those modules are notoriously under spec, so get a 10A one and use it for 5A. Add another module in the future if you want to drive another string.